# How many java KeyCodes are there in KeyEvent?

Tags: java, keyevent, keycode

How many codes can be returned by KeyEvent.getKeyCode()?

What is the range of the codes returned by KeyEvent.getKeyCode()?

Are the KeyCodes listed on the [javadoc for KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) (VK_?) the only KeyCodes that can be returned, or are there more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there are any such guarantees, judging by this paragraph from the documentation:

> WARNING: Aside from those keys that are defined by the Java language (VK_ENTER, VK_BACK_SPACE, and VK_TAB), do not rely on the values of the VK_ constants. Sun reserves the right to change these values as needed to accomodate a wider range of keyboards in the future.

Comment: So key codes could range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 -- the range of the Integer?

Comment: I guess it is useful to note that the current [list of VK_? codes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html) seems to have a trend of staying under 65535, the maximum unsigned 16-bit number. If you'd like to include this in your answer it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These are all KeyCodes that can be returned by Key* method.